# Phonertc ionic demo cordova is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonertc

I am a newbie with ionic and trying to install phonertc on ionic platform but when i run the app it shows for VideoViewDirective that RefrenceError: cordova is undefined.

VideoViewDirective.js

```
angular.module('phonertcdemo')
  .directive('videoView', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  template: '<div class="video-container"></div>',
  replace: true,
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    function updatePosition() {
    cordova.plugins.phonertc.setVideoView({
        container: element[0],
        local: { 
          position: [240, 240],
          size: [50, 50]
        }
      });
    }

    $timeout(updatePosition, 500);
    $rootScope.$on('videoView.updatePosition', updatePosition);
  }
}
});
```

Comment: Have you included `cordova.js` on index page?

Comment: Yes Pankaj..i have included cordova.js in my index.html. Pease help me out bcoz i am stuck there for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I first started.  I made sure to declair com.dooble.phonert as a plugin.  Then, I only referenced cordova.js in my index.html.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running using ionic serve, it is expected to show cordova is undefined.

If you want to run it in browser, you should

```
ionic platform add browser
ionic run browser
```

Then you will be able to use part of cordova in your browser.