# Ionic 2 Runtime Error: Cordova is undefined

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

When I tried to run my Ionic v3.14.0 hybrid app in browser, I got the runtime error "Cordova is undefined". I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383076/phonertc-ionic-demo-cordova-is-undefined) post's answer and ran the below commands

```
ionic cordova platform add browser
ionic cordova run browser
```

The first command above added `Platforms/browser` to my project and a folder structure beneath it and I can find `cordova.js` under `Platforms/browser/www`.
However when I run the 2nd comman above, a blank chrome browser instance opens (though my default is IE) and remains blank without showing up the app. Below is the stack trace from the terminal.

```
PS C:\Data\Per\Biz\Ionic\MyApp> ionic cordova run browser
Running app-scripts build: --platform browser --target cordova
[00:47:27]  build dev started ...
[00:47:27]  clean started ...
[00:47:27]  clean finished in 12 ms
[00:47:27]  copy started ...
[00:47:27]  deeplinks started ...
[00:47:28]  deeplinks finished in 113 ms
[00:47:28]  transpile started ...
[00:47:31]  transpile finished in 3.71 s
[00:47:31]  preprocess started ...
[00:47:31]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
[00:47:31]  webpack started ...
[00:47:32]  copy finished in 4.39 s
[00:47:41]  webpack finished in 9.49 s
[00:47:41]  sass started ...
[00:47:42]  sass finished in 1.40 s
[00:47:42]  postprocess started ...
[00:47:42]  postprocess finished in 16 ms
[00:47:42]  lint started ...
[00:47:42]  build dev finished in 15.21 s
> cordova run browser
Error loading cordova-browser

Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Data\Per\Biz\Ionic\MyApp\platforms\browser\cordova\build.bat""

Cleaning Browser project
[00:47:46]  lint finished in 4.18 s
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Data\Per\Biz\Ionic\MyApp\platforms\browser\cordova\run.bat --nobuild""
Static file server running @ http://localhost:8000/index.html
CTRL + C to shut down
200 /index.html (gzip)
200 /cordova.js (gzip)
200 /build/main.js (gzip)
200 /build/polyfills.js (gzip)
200 /build/main.css (gzip)
200 /cordova_plugins.js (gzip)
200 /plugins/cordova-plugin-device/www/device.js (gzip)
200 /plugins/cordova-plugin-device/src/browser/DeviceProxy.js (gzip)
200 /plugins/com.salesforce/www/com.salesforce.plugin.oauth.js (gzip)
200 /plugins/com.salesforce/www/com.salesforce.plugin.network.js (gzip)
200 /plugins/com.salesforce/www/com.salesforce.plugin.sdkinfo.js (gzip)
200 /plugins/com.salesforce/www/com.salesforce.plugin.smartstore.js (gzip)
200 /plugins/com.salesforce/www/com.salesforce.plugin.smartstore.client.js (gzip)
200 /plugins/com.salesforce/www/com.salesforce.plugin.sfaccountmanager.js (gzip)
200 /plugins/com.salesforce/www/com.salesforce.plugin.smartsync.js (gzip)
200 /plugins/com.salesforce/www/com.salesforce.util.bootstrap.js (gzip)
200 /plugins/com.salesforce/www/com.salesforce.util.event.js (gzip)
200 /plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/www/browser/keyboard.js
200 /plugins/com.salesforce/www/com.salesforce.util.exec.js (gzip)
200 /plugins/com.salesforce/www/com.salesforce.util.logger.js (gzip)
200 /plugins/com.salesforce/www/com.salesforce.util.promiser.js (gzip)
200 /plugins/com.salesforce/www/com.salesforce.util.push.js (gzip)
200 /plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/www/splashscreen.js (gzip)
200 /plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/src/browser/SplashScreenProxy.js (gzip)
200 /config.xml (gzip)
404 /screen
200 /build/vendor.js (gzip)
200 /assets/icon/favicon.ico (gzip)
```

I have included `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` in index.html

Below are my ts files where I declared Cordova:
**data-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

declare let cordova:any;

/*
  Generated class for the DataServiceProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class DataServiceProvider {
  indexSpecs:any[];
  soupName = "menuItems"; 

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello DataServiceProvider Provider');
  }

  getMainMenu(){
    return this.http.get('assets/data/mainmenu.json')
    .map((response:Response)=>response.json().Categories);
  }

  getMainMenuItems() {
    this.registerSmartStoreSoup();
  }

  registerSmartStoreSoup() {
    this.indexSpecs = [{path:"Name",type:"string"},{path:"Id",type:"string"}];
    cordova.require("com.salesforce.plugin.smartstore").registerSoup(this.soupName,this.indexSpecs,this.successCallback,this.errorCallback);
  }

  successCallback() {
    console.log("Soup "+this.soupName+" Created Successfully");
  }

  errorCallback(err) {
    console.log("Error Creating "+this.soupName+":"+err)
  }

}
```

getMainMenuItems() from above is called in the constructor of **app.component.ts**

```
constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen, public dataService: DataServiceProvider) {
    this.initializeApp();

    this.dataService.getMainMenuItems();
```

I am suspicious of the output `"Error loading cordova-browser"` in the stack trace above. But not sure of the issue here. Can someone please help me, I am struck here for a while.

Comment: are you trying to run your application in browser? try ionic serve command

Comment: @PrithiviRaj: Thanks for your response. When I try running with `ionic serve` I get `Runtime Error: 'cordova' is undefined`.

Comment: I got around the issue `"Error loading cordova-browser"` in the stack trace by upgrading to Cordova 6.5.0. However, I still see a blank page in Chrome when I try `ionic cordova run browser`

Comment: Following the solution [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/pwa-localhost-8000-screen-404-not-found-and-google-analytics-proxy-error/82011/5) I'm able to open the app in browser using `ionic cordova run browser`. However when I try `ionic serve -l` I get runtime error `'cordova' is undefined`. Presently I have only browser added under platforms. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Link you are referring is using Ionic 1 I guess. Please try the below steps.

1. delete node module folder and run `npm install -g ionic@latest`
2. run `ionic serve` directly to run in the browser.
3. install cordova if you want to run for devices `npm install -g cordova`

please refer the [official documentation for commands](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/)

Comment: Thanks for your response again. I still get the same error `'cordova' is undefined` running with `ionic serve -l`. I'm running Ionic 3.14.0 which I believe is the latest.

Comment: Should I install the Project Dependencies after the 1npm install -g ionic@latest`?

Comment: yes update the project dependencies after updating ionic version upgrade

Comment: Done. And `ionic serve -l` ==> 'cordova' is undefined

Answer (score 0):

The com.salesforce.plugin **Doesn't have support for Browser.** It only supports Mobile platforms ( ie. Android and iOS ).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm don't need to build for browser. I only need to build for ios & android. However, I use `ionic serve -l` to preview the changes in the app context. But after adding `cordova.require` I get an error 'cordova' is undefined. So I thought adding browser as platform is a work around. All I want in this case is preview the app in browser within the app look and feel, for which I believe I have to use `ionic serve -l` but that is blocked by the 'cordova' is undefined error. Can you please suggest a work around for this?

Comment: If you just want to preview the UI , Then on the " cordova undefined error " page .. You will find the "Close" option on top right. This will close the error dialog and your UI will be visible again. Hope this Helps !

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also need to test the functionality involving salesforce. From my findings, `ionic serve -l` can't help further since it doesn't support cordova. So I've started with android emulator. I'm struck with setting up the emulator with the below error: `emulator:ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAXM is not installed on this machine`. Android SDK Manager says `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) 6.2.1 Not compatible with windows`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Check BIOS of your system, the Virtualization needs to Enabled for HAXM to work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I downloaded HAXM from Intel for Windows and it's working now.